Merge several tables into one where tables have the same columns but only add rows where unique values exist on one column
The below code works to insert rows into table_main on an mySQL database where table_A contains unique values from the column primary_isbn13
INSERT INTO `table_main`
SELECT * FROM `table_A` A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `table_main` X 
                  WHERE A.`primary_isbn13` = X.`primary_isbn13`)

I have several tables to merge into table_main where unique primary_isbn13 exist.  Rather then keep running the same sql statement several times replacing table_A with table_B then table_C etc is there a way to SELECT several tables - table_A, table_B and table_C and merge them into table_main where unique primary_isbn13 values exist?

Does the order of tables matter? ie do any primary_isbn13 values appear in more than one of the "tableX" tables?

@Bohemian there will be duplicate primary_isbn13 values in the tables I'm merging but I'd like to remove any duplicate rows where primary_isbn is the same

If primary_isbn13 must be unique then the table structure must contain either primary or unique index by this column. If so then use simple INSERT IGNORE - the duplicates will be ignored and won't be inserted-automatically.

@user1233894 How do you determine which duplicates to remove, or is it that the data in the other tables is the same for a given primary_isbn13? Please supply sample data to cover such edge cases and show expected result, ideally with a link to a db fiddle

Use UNION:
INSERT INTO table_main
SELECT * FROM table_A A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_main X WHERE A.primary_isbn13 = X.primary_isbn13)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_B B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_main X WHERE B.primary_isbn13 = X.primary_isbn13)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_C C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_main X WHERE C.primary_isbn13 = X.primary_isbn13)


@Bohenian I got the code working but it doesn't not remove rows where primary_isbn13 has duplicates

Needed to make primary_isbn13 unique aka primary key in table structure then run
INSERT IGNORE INTO main_table
SELECT * FROM table_A;
INSERT IGNORE INTO main_table
SELECT * FROM table_B;
INSERT IGNORE INTO main_table
SELECT * FROM table_C;

